# C++ Visitor Pattern with visitor over subclassed nodes loses "is a" relationship

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

First, sorry if this is a duplicate. I didn't see anything similar though.

I'm familiar with the visitor pattern and I'm trying to add a little bit more flexibility for the visitor on my graph. If I have node classes A,B,C, SubB (inherits B), I would like to be able to have a visitor that accepts B nodes and will automatically accept SubB nodes without knowing about them (defining the accept()).

The obvious benefit is that I can subclass all day and the visitor doesn't need to care about the defining a visit for those types.

I have code and results to demonstrate below.
As you can see, here are the nodes it will visit.

> ```
> new Node(),
> new ANode(),
> new BNode(),
> new CNode(),
> new BNode(),
> new SubBNode()
> ```

Basically the CountVisitor correctly reports it found 2 Bs, and I understand why. CountVisitor.visit(SubB&) isn't overridden and will redirect to Visitor.visit(SubB&) instead, thus skipping the count.  However, I would like the functionality where it reports 3 ( 2 Bs + 1 SubB ) because SubB "is a" B. I've thought about this and I just can't figure out how to make the type system do it. How should I rearrange things to achieve that functionality? I'm also open to alternative patterns if that maintains the "is a" relationship but I do think the visitor would be perfect if this snag was resolved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Visitor;

class Node
{
  public:
  vector<Node*> children;
  virtual void accept(Visitor&);
};

class ANode : public Node
{
  public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&);

};
class BNode : public Node
{
  public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&);
};
class CNode : public Node
{
  public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&);
};

//-- try inheritance

class SubBNode: public BNode
{
  public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&);
};

//--

class Visitor 
{
  public:
  virtual void visit(Node& n);
  virtual void visit(ANode& n);
  virtual void visit(BNode& n);
  virtual void visit(CNode& n);
  virtual void visit(SubBNode& n);
};

class CountVisitor : public Visitor
{
  public:
  virtual void visit(BNode& n);

  int count = 0;
  void print();
};
//---------------------------------------------

void Node::accept(Visitor& v){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  v.visit(*this);
}
void ANode::accept(Visitor& v){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  v.visit(*this);
}
void BNode::accept(Visitor& v){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  v.visit(*this);
}
void CNode::accept(Visitor& v){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  v.visit(*this);
}
void SubBNode::accept(Visitor& v){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  v.visit(*this);
}
// -----
void Visitor::visit(Node& n){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDEFAULT" << endl;
}
void Visitor::visit(ANode& n){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDEFAULT" << endl;
}
void Visitor::visit(BNode& n){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDEFAULT" << endl;
}
void Visitor::visit(CNode& n){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDEFAULT" << endl;
}
void Visitor::visit(SubBNode& n){
  cout <<  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDEFAULT" << endl;
}
// -----
void CountVisitor::visit(BNode& n){
  count++;
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tSPECIAL" << endl;
}
void CountVisitor::print(){
  cout << "CountVisitor Found Bs: "<< count << endl;
}


// ====================================================

int main() {

  cout << "======FLAT TEST======" << endl;
  vector<Node*> nodes = {
    new Node(),
    new ANode(),
    new BNode(),
    new CNode(),
    new BNode(),
    new SubBNode()
  };

  cout << "--DEFAULT--" << endl;
  Visitor v1;
  for( Node* n : nodes ){
    n->accept(v1);
  }

  cout << "--COUNT--" << endl;
  CountVisitor cv1;
  for( Node* n : nodes ){
    n->accept(cv1);
  }
  cv1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

RESULTS

```
======FLAT TEST======
--DEFAULT--
virtual void Node::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(Node&)      DEFAULT
virtual void ANode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(ANode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void BNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(BNode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void CNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(CNode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void BNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(BNode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void SubBNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(SubBNode&)      DEFAULT
--COUNT--
virtual void Node::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(Node&)      DEFAULT
virtual void ANode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(ANode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void BNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void CountVisitor::visit(BNode&)        SPECIAL
virtual void CNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(CNode&)     DEFAULT
virtual void BNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void CountVisitor::visit(BNode&)        SPECIAL
virtual void SubBNode::accept(Visitor&)
virtual void Visitor::visit(SubBNode&)      DEFAULT
CountVisitor Found Bs: 2
```

Comment: Can you just get rid of the visit(SubBNode& n) method in your Visitor class?  It seems like then you would get the behavior you want.

Comment: True, except if I have another visitor that is designed to only do something with SubB types, then it won't be possible to respond to those nodes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an additional layer, something like:

```
template <typename F>
class FunctorVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    explicit FunctorVisitor (F& f) : f(f) {}

    virtual void visit(Node& n) override { f(n);}
    virtual void visit(ANode& n) override { f(n);}
    virtual void visit(BNode& n) override { f(n);}
    virtual void visit(CNode& n) override { f(n);}
    virtual void visit(SubBNode& n) override { f(n);}
private:
    F& f;
};


class CountVisitor
{
public:
    void operator() (const Node& n) const {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tDefault" << endl;
    }
    void operator() (const BNode& n) {
        count++;
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\t\tSPECIAL" << endl;
    }

    int count = 0;
    void print() const {
        cout << "CountVisitor Found Bs: "<< count << endl;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ABSZbj)